# Verifying that a protected super method is invoked

Tags: java, junit, verification, jmockit

I have the following structure:

```
class Bar{
  ....
  protected void restore(){
    ....
  }

  ....
}
```

This class is extended by `Foo` as below:

```
class Foo extends Bar{
    ....

    @Override
    public void restore(){  //valid override
        super.restore();

        ....
    }
}
```

In my jUnit test I would like to test that when `foo.restore()` is called, the `super.restore()` is called subsequently. Hence, below is my jUnit test method:

```
class FooTest{
  @Tested
  Foo _foo;

  @Test
  void testRestore(final Bar bar){

    new Expectations(){{
      bar.restore(); times = 1; // Error! bar.restore() not visible
    }};

    Deencapsulation.invoke(_foo,"restore");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, my test cannot compile. The reason is that 1) the `restore()` of the parent is `protected` and 2) `FooTest` and `Foo` exist together in a separate project (and therefore folder) vs. `Bar`.

Is there anyway to achieve the desired test? I have checked the [jMockit tutorials](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html) (many times over the past few months) and have not seen a similar test (same goes for a search on Google).

---

**Update**

With the help of the responses, I understand that enforcing subclasses to invoke `super` is not the best practice, yet this is not my implementation and I *still* have to test it. I am still looking for a way to enforce my jUnit test to check if the call to the parent is taking place.

Comment: As a side-note: Requiring a class to call super() is regarded as a minor code smell. See: http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html

Comment: @MicSim thanks, I had no clue that this was the case (although I didn't even code it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following test should work:

```
public class FooTest
{
    @Tested Foo _foo;

    @Test
    void restoreInFooCallsSuper(@Mocked final Bar bar)
    {
        new Expectations() {{
            invoke(bar, "restore");
        }};

        _foo.restore();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting that `Invocations` have an `invoke()` method as well as `Deencapsulation` (which I have statically imported). This is not clearly explained in the tutorials but I have been able to locate a small example in there.

Comment: [This section](http://jmockit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/www/tutorial/BehaviorBasedTesting.html#deencapsulation) of the Tutorial is meant to explain that.

Answer (score 4):

So basically you are trying to enforce a contract of calling the super and trying to allow for subclassing?  I think that this is not easily done due to the dynamic dispatch that will hide the behavior in Java. I don't think that Mocking will catch this.

A way the ensure that the super is called would be to break out the super and the extension into 2 methods like

```
class Foo {
  public final void restore() {
    //parent code...
    doRestore();
  }

  protected void doRestore() {
    //empty base implementation
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    protected void doRestore() {
      //do my subclass specific restore stuff here
    } 
}
```

Comment: I have `Bar` as the parent and you have `Foo`, this is driving my OCD self insane.

Answer (score 1):

The `super.restore()` is supposed to do something useful no? some specific logic. In your test simply test that the outcome of invoking the `super.restore()` happened.

Another way to look into it is the following. In the subclass before doing anything you implement an `assert` that **ensures** that the super did its job correctly. This is a stronger check and is well known as part of Meyer's **[Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_contract)** paradigm. In this context the subclass simply checks that the post-condition of the `super.restore()` implementation holds before executing and by using `assert` you know it will fail during Unit Tests but also during test integration runs of your application e.g.

```
class Foo extends Bar{
    ....

    @Override
    public void restore(){  //valid override
        super.restore();
        assert super_restore_worked_ok_condition : "restore post-condition failed";

        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: If the subclass programmer forgets to invoke the super method they are surely not going to remember to assert that it worked as expected.

Comment: if `super.restore()` is so important, then something will be missing and the test should catch it, separate from the fact that the subclass implementation should also fail.